# Ansible AWX Custom Script for Local Inventory Not working

Tags: ansible, ansible-tower, ansible-awx

I have an Ansible AWX server setup within a container and have setup all bar Inventory of 3 local LAN virtual machines.

I am looking to add some already deployed virtual machines on my LAN for a test case, currently 3 hosts.

I was looking at custom dynamic inventory script like contained in link below, but does not seem to run correctly for me. I see an error in python syntax. I tried to upload anyway but get and error "needs to be a json dict" when run sync within inventories. This is also the line I have syntax error on line 32:

```
print json.dumps(self.inventory);
```

[Dynamic Inventory Script](https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/creating-custom-dynamic-inventories-ansible)

I am looking only to add the 3 host virtual machines or subnet to inventory to test some playbooks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This is also the line I have syntax error on line 32:
>
> `print json.dumps(self.inventory);`

That means it is very likely that your `python` is actually python 3, in which `print` became a function, not a keyword. Thus, you will want to do one, or perhaps both, of these things:

1. change `print json...` to `print(json.dumps(self.inventory))`
2. add a declaration to the top of the file to ensure the script will continue to behave rationally even when run on python 2:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env python
   from __future__ import print_function

   '''
   Example custom dynamic inventory script for Ansible, in Python.
   ```